# Как получить шрифт из QFontComboBox и установить его в поле QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

Собственно в этом и весь вопрос. У QfontComboBox нет метода value () или getValue (), а установить шрифт в текстовое поле нужно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод `QFont currentFont()` у `QFontComboBox`.
У `QFont` есть методы `toString()` и `fromString()`. С помощью которых можно преобразовать QFont в строку и обратно.